# Find the closest point to $b= (1,1,2,-2)^T$ spanned by three vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, pseudoinverse

***EDIT:*** @Will Jagy suggests that $A$ doesn't consist of linearly independent vectors. *Should I use the column space of the $A$ instead?*

Find the closest point and the distance from
$$b=
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
2\\
-2\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

To the subspace spanned by the vectors:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
2\\
-1\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
1\\
-2\\
-1\\
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0\\
3\\
2\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

---

I use $A^TAx^*=A^Tb$:
$$ A^TA=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & -2 & -1\\
1 & 0 & 3 & 2\\
\end{pmatrix}
*
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1\\
2 & 1 & 0\\
-1 & -2 & 3\\
0 & -1 & 2\\
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
6 & 4 & -2\\
4 & 6 & -8\\
-2 & -8 & 14\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

And

$$A^Tb=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & -2 & -1\\
1 & 0 & 3 & 2\\
\end{pmatrix}*
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
2\\
-2\\
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
-1\\
3\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Next, I set up:

$$
\left( \begin{array}{ccc|c}
  6&4&-2&1\\
  4&6&-8&-1\\
  -2&-8&14&3\\
\end{array} \right)
$$

Which leads me to:
$$x^*=
\begin{pmatrix}
1/2-z\\
-1/2+2z\\
z\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The closest point will be $w^*=Ax^*$

**Where did I go wrong? My final answer shouldn't depend on a variable because there should only be 1 unique closest point to a subspace**

Comment: Please edit your subject line. Don't make them too tall or too deep. It breaks navigation and didplays in the question list.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I don't know how. I think you can edit it if you want

Comment: You do it by not using matrix commands in the subject line, which are harder to use than to not use them.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I usually see vertical vectors. I didn't know it was too big

Comment: Anything that extends far past the normal line height and depth is too big for subject lines. Your vector was almost five times as big.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin since the question line got smaller, more of the preview of the question is shown so it's still big

Comment: Main problem is subject lines, not previews. Avoid them in subject lines. Body can be formatted. Preview does not appear on the main page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140564/discussion-between-cotton-headed-ninnymuggins-and-arturo-magidin).

Comment: meanwhile, the matrix you give as $A^T A$ does not have full rank.  Your three column vectors are dependent

Comment: I have no interest in doing so.

Comment: @WillJagy Yes I'm aware of that, so what do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method of computing the pseudo-inverse of $A$ does not work since that matrix does not have full rank; for instance, you can check that $[1,0,3,2]^T=[1,2,-1,0]^T-2[0,1,-2,-1]^T$. So, the space spanned by the three given vectors is simply the space spanned by $[1,2,-1,0]^T$ and by $[0,1,-2,-1]^T$.

So, take$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\2&1\\-1&-2\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}.$$Then $A^TA=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}6&4\\4&6\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ and then you will get $x^*=\left[\frac12,-\frac12\right]^T$. So the closest point is$$A.\begin{bmatrix}\frac12\\-\frac12\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac12\\\frac12\\\frac12\\\frac12\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense

Comment: I'm glad I could help.